# Iterating over an uneven set of numbers

Tags: c#, loops, set

I have a set of numbers in the form of `{ -1, 0, +1 }` which I have to iterate over using two loops, much like you would when using a 2D array.

The whole set then becomes every combination of the numbers above:
`{ -1, -1 } -> { +1, +1 }`, which is 9 in total.

However, the set `{ 0, 0 }` I have to skip. Normally I would just check with an if statement, but using this inside two nested loops will make it check for this condition on every run.

Is there an efficient way to  somehow do this?

**UPDATE:** I feel this deserves a little more detail, because there might be a completely different solution this problem than what I want to do above.

It is basicly to check adjacent cells within an array. So `{ 0, 0 }` is cell we are checking, but I wish to check every cell adjacent to it, not including the main cell.

Imagine we had a 2D array `int[,] array = new int[,] { ... };`
If we then access the array at any index approximately in the middle of it (not close to any edge index; like the bottom/top row or bottom/top column), our conceptual bird's eye view of the array would look like this:

```
[-1, -1] [-1, 0] [-1, +1]
[0, -1] [0, 0] [0, +1]
[+1, -1] [+1, 0] [+1, +1]
```

`[0,0]` is our current element. We can access every adjacent element/cell using the above numbers for [row,column].

A typical loop to do this would look like this:

```
for (int i = row-1; i <= row+1; ++i) {
    for (int j = col-1; j <= col+1; ++j) {
        if (i == row && j == col) continue;
            ...
    }
}
```

Can we avoid the if statement?

Comment: I don't think so, to leave this one out you have to check each combination if it is {0,0}. Are you actually sure this little `if` statement has such a significant impact on your loop's performance that it's worth thinking about?

Comment: @RenéVogt I'm sure it doesn't have that big of an impact on my program, but what if we were talking millions of iterations in some other program with the same problem?

Comment: @user3407764 Is that the situation you're actually in?  Don't worry about problems that you don't actually have.

Comment: But if you have a result set, and you want to filter out specific results (like `{0,0}` in your case), you _will have_ to check each single element, which is exactly what your if does. Can't see how to avoid that. And even in millions of iterations, this `if` will only have an effect if the condition is expensive (which is not the case when comparing two integers).

Comment: I updated the question to add a bit more context.

Comment: @RenéVogt No, you *don't* actually have to check every single item in the set in order to remove an item from a set (at least with a well implemented set, like `HashSet<T>`).   Note that checking the condition isn't too expensive, but if the result set is very large, then that not too expensive cost times a *very large* number *is* expensive.  Of course, that means it's only an issue if the OP actually has a very large result set.

Comment: @user3407764 And are you checking adjacency of an item with like 26 or several hundred dimensions or something, because that's what it'd take for this set to actually be large enough to be a problem.  If you only have 2, or even 3, then that number is just not big enough to care about.

Comment: @Servy If I said yes, would that justify the question?

Comment: I'm unclear from your comment about cells. Are you generating the offsets or the actual coordinates of the adjacent cells? ie can you just hardcode the eight values that you have and not do any logic at all?

Comment: @user3407764 If you said yes I don't think I'd believe you, but yes, if that were true it would mean it would actually be a question worth thinking about.

Comment: @Servy didn't think about (hash-)sets, I was thinking about _filtering_ by a condition (that may change), not by knowing the specific element to exclude.

Comment: @Chris If I could hardcode these numbers in it would be great, but I don't see how I could then use it the two loops without creating 16 separate loops.

Comment: @RenéVogt Hence why I mentioned it to you.  The problem *isn't* actually requesting an arbitrary predicate be performed on each item, that's just the OP's current (undesired) implementation.

Comment: @user3407764: My question is can you just say `pairs = {{-1,-1}, {-1,0}, {-1,1}, {0,-1}, {0,1}, {1,-1}, {1,0}, {1,1}}` (in pseudocode). And then just iterate over that set. I'm unclear on whether you'll always be iterating over `{-1,0,1}` or if sometimes you are looping over `{11,12,13}` and `{48,49,50}` and so on.

Comment: @Chris A typical loop would look like this: `for(int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; ++i) { for(int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; ++j) { ... } }` So we would iterate over every pair here, including the combination: `i = 0, j = 0` which is what I don't want to do. So no, hitting out of bounds wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It might be helpful if you showed the code you were using to create your sets, in order to reduce any confusion. Also what is the type of "set" you're using? Some collection types have a poorer performing `Add` operations than others that would be more costly than the `if`.

Comment: So you could put whatever is in your loop in a method and then just call it 8 times with the appropriate values... eg `Frob(row-1, col-1); Frob(row, col-1); Frob(row+1, col-1); etc.` but your code will probably be much less readable than just using the two loops and an if. That code it is obvious what its doing, any other code, not so much. So in this case I'd strongly advise go for readable rather than less readable code that is "optimised" in such a way that you would probably not even pick it up on any benchmarks.

Comment: Please post the two loops with manual check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, it seems you don't need loops at all and your desired result has 8 well defined elements.

So you coud simply create a little method that gives you all adjacent cells to your main cell:

```
Point[] GetAdjacentPoints(Point p)
{
    return new[]{
        new Point { X = p.X - 1, Y = p.Y - 1 },
        new Point { X = p.X,     Y = p.Y - 1 },
        new Point { X = p.X + 1, Y = p.Y - 1 },
        new Point { X = p.X - 1, Y = p.Y },
        // leave out p itself
        new Point { X = p.X + 1, Y = p.Y },
        new Point { X = p.X - 1, Y = p.Y + 1},
        new Point { X = p.X,     Y = p.Y + 1},
        new Point { X = p.X + 1, Y = p.Y + 1}
    };
}
```

(I assume `Point` to be something like `struct Point {public int X {get;set;} public int Y {get;set;}}` or any other type to hold two integers).

You can use this method like this:

```
foreach(Point adjacent in GetAdjacentPoints(new Point {X = 0, Y = 0})
    Console.WriteLine($"X: {adjacent.X} Y: {adjacent.Y}");
```

Output:

```
X: -1 Y: -1
X: 0 Y: -1
X: 1 Y: -1
X: -1 Y: 0
X: 1 Y: 0
X: -1 Y: 1
X: 0 Y: 1
X: 1 Y: 1
```

Comment: I think hardcoding is the way forward but given we are talking about micro-optimizations then I do wonder if it will be quicker to just do the 9 if checks compared to creating a new array to iterate over... :)

Comment: @Chris well yes... the performance question is well answered by Servy. Back to the "adjacent cell" problem - with a result set of 8 or 9 elements optimization really doesn't matter imho. Of course one could cache the arrays again if you have to access them in tight loops,

Comment: Yeah, I'm being slightly facetious (or maybe the opposite of that, I'm not sure). :)

Answer (score 0):

Just compute every single pair and then remove the one pair you want to exclude from your final set.  [well implemented] Sets are specifically designed for efficient removal (more efficient than linear anyway, O(1) for hash based sets, O(log(n)) for tree based sets), so that will be faster than checking every single value in the set, which is what you would be doing by having the check in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you measure it first and see if this is really a problem, because depending on the type of collection you're using, the `Add` operation may be more costly than the `if` statement (in my case below, it consists of creating a new list and then adding that list to another list).

For example, using a `List<int>` to hold the original set, and a `List<List<int>>` to hold the combinations, I find that using the `if` statement is ***faster*** than not using it (and if we don't use it then we still need to iterate over the pairs to find the ones we want to remove).

Below is the test I ran, using loops *with* the `if` and *without* the `if`, with 2001 items in the set (from -1000 to 1000), which creates a total of `4004000` sets. I ran the tests in a loop 100 times and displayed the average time in an attempt to get the most accurate result:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(-1000, 2001).ToList();
    var combinations = new List<List<int>>();
    var withIfCount = new List<long>();
    var withoutIfCount = new List<long>();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    // Both test are run 100 times
    for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        for (int outer = 0; outer < items.Count; outer++)
        {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < items.Count; inner++)
            {
                if (outer == 0 && inner == 0) continue;
                combinations.Add(new List<int> {outer, inner});
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        withIfCount.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        combinations.Clear();

        sw.Restart();
        for (int outer = 0; outer < items.Count; outer++)
        {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < items.Count; inner++)
            {
                combinations.Add(new List<int> {outer, inner});
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        withoutIfCount.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        combinations.Clear();
    }

    // Display averages
    Console.WriteLine("Average time with 'if': " + withIfCount.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Average time without 'if': " + withoutIfCount.Average());

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I see you've updated your question with more detail that seems to contradict what you first stated. I'll leave this here for now in case it's helpful to someone else.